# box2d : camera and body not synced

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

i'm trying to make a program with Box2D and libgdx that makes the character jump on a static body (here, a circle). But my camera (that is following the dynamic body (the player)) keeps going down, even if my character stays on top of the circle as intended. So my questions are :
1) Why my camera keeps falling down, when it's supposed to follow the "playerBody" that is staying on top of the static body ?
2) Why my camera bounce when I press the Z key, but not  my playerbody ?

Thanks in advance. You may try to run it in eclipse, to see better what I mean, here's what I put in my Activity class :

(I got no errors/warnings at all.)

```
//private SpriteBatch batch;
//private Texture texture;
//private Sprite sprite;
//public Body body;
World world;
Body playerBody;
Body planetBody;
CircleShape planetCircle;
PolygonShape playerBox;
OrthographicCamera camera;
Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;  
static final float BOX_STEP=1/60f;  
static final int BOX_VELOCITY_ITERATIONS=6;  
static final int BOX_POSITION_ITERATIONS=2;  
static final float WORLD_TO_BOX=0.01f;  
static final float BOX_WORLD_TO=100f;
boolean jump = false;
long lastGroundTime = 0;

@Override
public void create() {

    world = new World(new Vector2(0, -50), true);
    debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();  
    camera.viewportHeight = 320;  
    camera.viewportWidth = 480;  
    camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth * .5f, camera.viewportHeight * .5f, 0f); 
    camera.update();
    //Ground body

    /*BodyDef groundBodyDef =new BodyDef();  
    groundBodyDef.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2 - 100 + 125);  
    Body groundBody = world.createBody(groundBodyDef);  
    PolygonShape groundBox = new PolygonShape();  
    groundBox.setAsBox((camera.viewportWidth) * 2, 10.0f);  
    groundBody.createFixture(groundBox, 0.0f);
    */

    //Planet

    BodyDef planetDef = new BodyDef();
    planetDef.type = BodyType.StaticBody;
    planetDef.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2 - 100);
    Body planetBody = world.createBody(planetDef);
    CircleShape planetCircle = new CircleShape();
    planetCircle.setRadius(125f);
    FixtureDef planetFixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    planetFixtureDef.shape = planetCircle;
    planetFixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
    //planetFixtureDef.friction = 0.0f;
    //planetFixtureDef.restitution = 0;
    planetBody.createFixture(planetFixtureDef);

    //Player

    BodyDef playerBodyDef = new BodyDef();
    playerBodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
    playerBodyDef.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2 - 100 + 125 + 50);
    playerBody = world.createBody(playerBodyDef);
    PolygonShape playerBox = new PolygonShape();
    playerBox.setAsBox(5.0f, 15.0f);
    FixtureDef playerFixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    playerFixtureDef.shape = playerBox;
    playerFixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
    //playerFixtureDef.friction = 1.0f;
    //playerFixtureDef.restitution = 1;
    playerBody.createFixture(playerFixtureDef);
    playerBody = world.createBody(playerBodyDef);

    //Dynamic Body  
    /*BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();  
    bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;  
    bodyDef.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2);  
    Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);  
    CircleShape dynamicCircle = new CircleShape();  
    dynamicCircle.setRadius(5f);  
    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();  
    fixtureDef.shape = dynamicCircle;  
    fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;  
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.0f;  
    fixtureDef.restitution = 1;  
    body.createFixture(fixtureDef); */

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    /*batch.dispose();
    texture.dispose();*/
    /*dynamicCircle.dispose();
    groundBox.dispose();*/
    playerBox.dispose();
    planetCircle.dispose();
}

@Override
public void render() {
    //Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    update();
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    /*batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    //sprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();*/
    camera.position.set(playerBody.getPosition().x, playerBody.getPosition().y, 0);
    camera.update();
    //camera.apply(Gdx.gl10);   
    debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);
    world.step(BOX_STEP, BOX_VELOCITY_ITERATIONS, BOX_POSITION_ITERATIONS);
    //playerBody.setAwake(true);
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

public void update()
{
    if(jump == true /*Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Gdx.input.)*/ && grounded() == true)
    {
        playerBody.setLinearVelocity(0, 0);
        playerBody.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0,150), new Vector2(playerBody.getPosition().x, playerBody.getPosition().y));
        jump = false;
    }
    //playerBody.setTransform(new Vector2(camera.viewportWidth / 2, playerBody.getPosition().y), playerBody.getAngle());
    //planetBody.setTransform(new Vector2(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2), 0);
}
@Override
public void resume() {
}

@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
//if(keycode == Keys.S) 
return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
if(keycode == Keys.Z)
    jump = true;
return false;
}

public boolean grounded()
{
    if(playerBody.getPosition().y <= ((camera.viewportHeight / 2) - 100 + 125))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating two `playerBody` in the world.  The second one is assigned but has no fixture.  This is the one you are manipulating in your code and your camera is following.  Remove the second `playerBody = world.createBody(playerBodyDef);` and it should work (better).

Comment: thanks! I'll be more cautious next time, but I looked very hard and did not notice it by myself

Comment: and I figured I needed to do in the Impulse or Force a value like 100 000, otherwise it would not move. do you have an explanation? Thanks.

Comment: @user2687718 please create new questions.  SO is no forum as such but a Q&A platform.  but a general suspect: box2d works in meters, newtons, ... SI units.  Using pixels will result in strange behaviour like you are seeing.

Comment: But I never use pixels. Like I did the gravity of my world as -100m/s^2, and I put applyforcetocenter as like 150 000 newton to make it move noticeably. So it means the mass of the default body is like very big? And i'll remember for the next question, sorry again.